# How to share common actions (or activities) between multiple navigation graphs?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using navigation library in my Android application with multiple activities and I would like to know, whether there is a way to share some actions (which do open certain page with predefined arguments) between multiple navigation graphs.

It goes like this:

1. There exists *ActivityB* which needs arguments *a*, *b*, *c* in its navigation action.
2. *ActivityA* has *NavGraphA* which opens *ActivityB*.
3. *ActivityC* has *NavGraphC* which also opens *ActivityB*.

Now I would like to use action which opens *ActivityB* in both *NavGraphA* and *NavGraphC*, preferably without duplicating the activity, its arguments and action itself in both graphs (e.g. some sort of include?).

I know that it is possible to define *ActivityB* as activity element in both graphs, but then I need to again define action with the same arguments all over again.

I will need to do something like this in both graphs:

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/xyFragment"
            android:name="x.y.fragment"
            android:label="xyFragment" >
        <action
                android:id="@+id/action_xyFragment_to_ActivityB"
                app:destination="@id/activityB" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
            android:id="@+id/activityB"
            android:name="x.y.ActivityB"
            android:label="ActivityB" >
        <argument
                android:name="a"
                app:argType="argument.A" />
        <argument
                android:name="b"
                app:argType="argument.B" />
        <argument
                android:name="c"
                app:argType="argument.C" />
    </activity>
```

As you can see - I can either wrap those arguments into one class, which will reduce the amount of arguments, but the original problem will still be there.

Or I can just duplicate it with different ids.

Maybe there is a way to somehow include shared global action across multiple graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global action to create a common action that multiple destinations can use.

Add ActivityB either in NavGraphA or NavGraphC, then make it as global by right click -> add action -> global on navigation design view.

So both ActivityA & ActivityC can navigate to ActivityB by using it id: eg. R.id.action_global_activityB
[image]

Refer [Global actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action) for more details.